# Middleware access to User is always null but controller can access fine

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-5

I have added authentication to my application with Microsoft.
This is working, I can see the user, I am redirected to login, all good.

BUT, if I try to access the user details in middleware, they are always null?
In the controller I can read everything fine.

```
public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    private readonly ILogger<CustomMiddleware> _logger;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<CustomMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    // IMyScopedService is injected into Invoke
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {

        _logger.LogInformation("WE ARE HERE {0}", httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

> **[Information] WE ARE HERE &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& null**

The controller

```
[HttpGet("private")]
    public IActionResult Private() {
        var user = new { User.Identity.Name, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, User.Identity.AuthenticationType };
        return Ok(user);
    }
```

> { name: "example@gmail.com", isAuthenticated: true,
> authenticationType: "AuthenticationTypes.Federation" }

I have tried with two methods of middleware registration but both are doing the same thing.

```
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, ExampleStartupFilter>();
```

Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Need your Startup.cs?

Comment: .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {

Answer (score 7):

In short It is upto which point you are applying middlerware.In startup.cs in Configure method you have to put method following way.

If you put your middle after

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>(); // This is your middleware.
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, solved and ofc it was daft.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
```

I just needed to move my registration in the start-up to AFTER the auth options.
** Order is important